# Open skype chat page from ios app

Tags: ios, swift

I want to Open a user skype chat page from my iOS app. If user is not logged in then skype should display login page and after login skype should display chat page. is it possible in iPhone , if yes how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Skype's public API [here](http://www.skype.com/en/developer/). I don't believe there's a framework for it that can be easily imported so you'll need to look into it more. Hope that helps